# Change the date format of created_at in as_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I don't know much about ruby/rails. My app is currently producing some json to be consumed by message-bus:

```
  message: act.as_json({
    only: [:id, :body, :direction, :kind, :sent, :is_read, :created_at, :call_tag],
    methods: [:delivering?, :attach_list, :voicemail_url, :status, :status_msg]
  })
```

The data is coming back fine, the only problem is the created_at date is in an undesirable format: `2018-04-17 01:57:32 UTC`. I'd like it in iso8601: `2018-04-17T01:54:20.026Z`. In my controllers, jbuilder is being used and is returning json in the correct format. My search for a solution has led me to ActiveSupport, trying to somehow use jbuilder within this publish method of message-bus, to_json, etc. Is there some way to set `created_at` to a custom value/format? If not, is there a reason why as_json is using this other format and jbuilder is using iso8601? Thanks

Comment: as_json is a stringified version of json itself. string of a time stamp such as Time.now.to_s gives "2018-04-17 01:57:32 UTC". using "2018-04-17 01:57:32 UTC".to_time.iso8601 should solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the created_at on the corresponding model

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def created_at
    attributes['created_at'].strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
  end
end
```

And of course don't forget to adjust the format as you want

Then calling .created_at should return the values in the format you specified

Answer (score 1):

Rails 6 Override created_at everywhere

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  def created_at
    attributes['created_at'].strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
  end
end
```

Or localize

```
  include ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper
  #...
  def created_at
    l(attributes['created_at'],  :format => "%d %B /%Y %H:%M")
  end
  #...
```